# Python27 Is it able to make timer without thread.Timer?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, websocket

So, basically I want to make timer but I don't want to use `thread.Timer` for
efficiency

- Python produces thread by itself, it is not efficient and better not to use it. 
  I search the essay related to this. And checked It is slow to use thread. 
  e.g) single process was divided into N, and made it work into Thread, It was slower.

However I need to use Thread for this.

```
class Works(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.symbol_dict = config.ws_api.get("ASSET_ABBR_LIST")
    self.dict = {}
    self.ohlcv1m = []

    def on_open(self, ws):
        ws.send(json.dumps(config.ws_api.get("SUBSCRIPTION_DICT")))
```

everytime I get the message form web socket server, I store in self.dict

```
    def on_message(self,ws,message):
    message = json.loads(message)

    if len(message) > 2 :

        ticker = message[2]
        pair = self.symbol_dict[(ticker[0])]
        baseVolume = ticker[5]
        timestmap = time.time()

        try:
            type(self.dict[pair])
        except KeyError as e:
            self.dict[pair] = []


        self.dict[pair].append({
            'pair':pair,
            'baseVolume' : baseVolume,
            })



    def run(self):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            url = config.ws_api.get("WEBSOCK_HOST"),
            on_message = self.on_message,
            on_open = self.on_open
            )
        ws.run_forever(sslopt = {"cert_reqs":ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

'once in every 60s it occurs. calculate self.dict and save in to self.ohlcv1m
and will sent it to db. eventually self.dict and self.ohlcv1m initialized again to store 1min data from server'

```
    def every60s(self):
        threading.Timer(60, self.every60s).start()
        for symbol in self.dict:
            tickerLists = self.dict[symbol]
            self.ohlcv1m.append({
           "V": sum([
                    float(ticker['baseVolume']) for ticker in tickerLists]      
                    })

        #self.ohlcv1m will go to database every 1m 
            self.ohlcv1 = [] #init again
            self.dict = {} #init again


if __name__  == "__main__":
    work=Works()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=work.run)
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
    work.every60s()
```

(sorry for the indention)

1. I am connecting to socket by running run_forever() and getting realtimedata
2. Every 60s I need to check and calculate the data

Is there any way to make 60s without thread in python27?

I will be so appreciate you answer If you give me any advice.
Thank you

Comment: There is some inefficiency in Python with threads when the work isn't IO bound but for the code you've got here it looks like you're trying to prematurely optimise this unnecessarily

Comment: Gricey I just added more code. It was my first time to ask question in here so forgive me! @Gricey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes down to if you need the code to run exactly every 60 seconds, or if you can just wait 60 seconds between runs (i.e. if the logic takes 5 seconds, it'll run every 65 seconds).

If you're happy with just a 60 second gap between runs, you could do

```
import time

while True:
    every60s()
    time.sleep(60)
```

If you're really set on not using threads but having it start every 60 seconds regardless of the last poll time, you could time the last execution and subtract that from 60 seconds to get the sleep time.

However, really, with the code you've got there you're not going to run into any of the issues with Python threads you might have read about. Those issues come in when you've got multiple threads all running at the same time and all CPU bound, which doesn't seem to be the case here unless there's some very slow, CPU intensive work that's not in your provided code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So actually thread issue in my code is not matter. Since I don't use multiple threads?